# Remove ip addresses from lines

Tags: grep, sed

I have a file.txt containing subdomains and ip addresses:

input:

```
104.112.200.252 www2test.google.com
104.112.200.252 www.google.com
104.211.52.69   voice.google.com
104.211.52.69  voice.google.com
psfthrpreprd1.oci.google.com
voice2.google.com
psfthrpreprd3.oci.google.com
voice.google.com
psfthrpreprd4.oci.google.com
```

But I want only subdomains as output:

```
www2test.google.com
www.google.com
voice.google.com
voice.google.com
psfthrpreprd.oci.google.com
psfthrpreprd1.oci.google.com
voice2.google.com
psfthrpreprd3.oci.google.com
voice.google.com
psfthrpreprd4.oci.google.com
```

any suggestions thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
awk '{print $NF}' file.txt
```

Comment: ip addresses are random

Comment: @KeeraHere the `awk` solution seems to work, regardless of the randomness of the IP addresses... have you actually taken a look at it?  (It works well from what I can tell)

Comment: thanks it worked can you please explain how it worked thanks again

Comment: oooh that just printed the second word!

Comment: @KeeraHere basically it 'splits' on whitespace, and the second item it finds is printed.  That's how it works with that `awk` example, and it works very well.

Comment: @ThomasWard sorry but I should ask the question more correctly, but I have edited it can you please guide me now

Comment: @KeeraHere that's a completely different question from the first.  That invalidates this answer, which is usually a 'bad thing'.  I'm sure pLumo might be able to come up with a working solution for you, however this is *USUALLY* when I would go to a Python solution rather than an in-built solution.

Comment: Yes, easy solution, use $NF to print the last field, instead always the second :-)  `cut` solution is out though ;-)

Comment: it's perfectly working Thank You!!!